# Should I retry on ENOENT errors?

Tags: node.js

I am a maintainer of [pnpm](https://github.com/pnpm/pnpm). We have a [piece of code](https://github.com/pnpm/package-requester/blob/a077d41b76825fda2f282745571054c1b2e0d939/src/packageRequester.ts#L521) that reads the `package.json` of the unpacked package almost immediately after unpacking.

Today this code failed with an `ENOENT` error (which means the file does not exist). We use `read-package-json` that uses `graceful-fs` under the hood to read the `package.json`. `graceful-fs` retries `fs.readFile()` on some error codes ([like EMFILE and ENFILE](https://github.com/isaacs/node-graceful-fs/blob/654d5a285ea92b6573d4042eb184a2a66c0f0749/graceful-fs.js#L74)) but not on `ENOENT`.

Could it be some Node.js or filesystem race condition? Should pnpm retry reading the package.json after an ENOENT error?

It happens very rarely and last time I have seen it, it happened on Node.js v9, Linux.

Comment: `ENOENT` means that the file you're trying to read doesn't exist. This obviously sounds like a fatal error that should be a reason to abort.

Comment: I know what the error means but there is no way the file is not there. Maybe I should try to re-unpack the tarball. It is hard to reproduce but as far as I remember, the file was there, so my _assumption_ is that it is some glitch because the read happens very fast after the write.

Comment: Are you sure it happens __after__ the write? With asynchronous operations reading might happen before unpacking.

Comment: yes, I am sure. Otherwise, it would fail a lot more frequently. pnpm is heavily used.

the unpacking happens in this piece of code that is above reading the file: https://github.com/pnpm/package-requester/blob/a077d41b76825fda2f282745571054c1b2e0d939/src/packageRequester.ts#L455-L481

Comment: Maybe in these rare cases https://github.com/pnpm/package-requester/blob/a077d41b76825fda2f282745571054c1b2e0d939/src/packageRequester.ts#L520 fails and the package isn't updated at all.